# Vue.js + typescriptで拡張メソッドを利用する方法

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Vue.js + typescriptの環境で自作クラスの拡張メソッドを作成しました。
eslintのエラーは発生しないのですが実行時エラー(`TypeError: .format is not a function`)が発生します。
babelでトランスコンパイルしていますが設定が関係していたりするのでしょうか？
解決策があればご教示願います。

具体的には以下のようなコードです。(一部省略)
main.jsでimportしています。

```
declare module "@/dto/messageDto" {
  interface MessageDto {
    format(...params: unknown[]): string;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(MessageDto.prototype, "format", {
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function (...params: unknown[]): string {
    const messageDto = this as MessageDto;
    return ~~~;
  },
});
```